Understanding the definition of irrational exponents by approximations using rational exponents
On my textbook I am presented with these definition of approximation that will be needed throughout the text, could you please try and explain what approximation is needed thanks.

You have evaluated $a^x$ for integer and rational values of $x$. For example, you know that $4^3 = 64$ and $4^{1/2}=2$. However, to evaluate $4^x$ for any real number $x$, you need to
interpret forms with irrational exponents. For the purposes of this text, it is sufficient to think of $a^{\sqrt{2}}$ (where $\sqrt{2}\approx 1.41421356$) as the number that has the successively closer approximations
$$a^{1.4}, a^{1.41}, a^{1.414}, a^{1.4142}, a^{1.41421}, \ldots$$

original image

As to the question, I'm not sure what you are asking.  A priori, something like $a^x$ is only defined for rationals.  We might try to extend the definition to all reals by defining $a^x$ as the limit of $a^{x_i}$ for some rational sequence $x_i$ converging to $x$.  Of course, you need to prove that this definition works.  Is that what you are asking?

It is more common these days to define, say, $e^x$ using power series, use that to define $\ln x$ and then define $4^x$ as $e^{x\ln 4}$.  But that's a different approach.

sorry Lulu for the confusion miss typed

Hm , basically we use that $a^x$ is continous for a positive real number $a$ , therefore this approximation works.

@Peter: You can hardly use the continuity of $a^x$ over $\Bbb R$ before you have defined what $a^x$ even means!

The text seems to be implying that its definition of $a^{\sqrt2}$ is $\lim_{n\to\infty} a^{r_n}$ where $(r_n)$ is a sequence of rational numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} r_n=\sqrt2$ (perhaps only this specific sequence, perhaps any increasing sequence, perhaps any sequence at all).

There are various ways of thinking of what an exponential function is. This wikipedia article explains 6 "characterizations" and it sounds like your textbook is asking you to think of it as characterization 6.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function

why am I getting downvoted?

Perhaps a specific example would help. According to the Windows calculator, we have
$$4^{\sqrt 2}=7.102993301316015400860\ldots$$
If we look at the sequence of approximations in your post, we get:
$$4^{1.4}=6.96440450636899311309\ldots$$
$$4^{1.41}=7.061623970325238932360\ldots$$
$$4^{1.414}=7.100890698155982429787\ldots$$
$$4^{1.4142}=7.102859756059511868231\ldots$$
$$4^{1.41421}=7.102958223286309604624\ldots$$
You can see how the approximations are getting closer and closer to the expected value. And all the exponents ($1.4,1.41,\ldots$) are finite decimals, therefore rational numbers. So we know how to compute these approximations.
So your text is saying that if $x$ is irrational, we can define $a^x$ as the limit of this sequence.
